# Probability associated with Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

I would like a nod in the right direction with the following problem.

> Let $0<t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n<\infty$, and  $\{a_i\}_1^n$ be real numbers,
>   find a function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ so that
>
> $$P\{B(t_1)\leq a_1, B(t_2)\leq a_2,\ldots, B(t_n)\leq a_n\}
> > =\int_{-\infty}^{a_n} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{a_1} f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n$$

My assumption is that you try to re-write the expression so that you can use the fact that Brownian motion has independent increments, however I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Do you mean $t_1 < t_2$?

Comment: Where you have $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{a_1} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{a_n} f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n$, I surmise you must have meant $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{a_n} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{a_1} f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: At $t_1$ you are at some number $b_1 \leq a_1$. At $t_2$ you are at some number $b_2 \leq a_2$, so you've moved a distance of $b_2-b_1$. Thus the probability that $b_2 \leq a_2$, conditioned on $B(t_1)=b_1$, is the probability that a $N(0,t_2-t_1)$ variable is in $(-\infty,a_2-b_1]$. Once you see how to write this case down in terms of integrals, the rest is routine induction.

Comment: So being a bit more explicit, $P(B(t_1) \leq a_1,B(t_2) \leq a_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{a_1} P(B(t_2) \leq a_2 \mid B(t_1)=b_1) f_{B(t_1)}(b_1) db_1$, where $f_X$ denotes the density of a continuous r.v. $X$.

Comment: Let $g_t(x)=e^{-x^2/2t}/\sqrt{2\pi t}$. Most definitions of Brownian motion that I am aware of, yield readily $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g_{t_1}(x_1)g_{t_2-t_1}(x_2-x_1)\cdots g_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(x_n-x_{n-1}).$$ So what is your definition?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed.  It seems perfectly clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$
Notice that for $i\le j$ we have
\begin{align}
& \cov(B(t_i),B(t_j)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \cov(B(t_i), (B(t_j)-B(t_i)) + B(t_i)) \\[10pt]
= {} & \cov(B(t_i), B(t_j)- B(t_i)) + \cov(B(t_i),B(t_i)) \\[10pt]
= {} & 0 + \var(B(t_i)) = t_i = t_{\min\{i,j\}} = \min\{t_i,t_j\}.
\end{align}

Hence
$$
\var\begin{bmatrix} B(t_1) \\  \vdots \\ B(t_n) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} t_1 & t_1 & t_1 & t_1 & \cdots & t_1 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_2 & t_2 & \cdots & t_2 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_3 & \cdots & t_3 \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & \cdots & t_4 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & \cdots & t_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Call this matrix $V$. then the joint density of this random vector whose variance is $V$ is
\begin{align}
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = {} & \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}^n}\cdot\frac 1 {(\det V)^{1/2}} \exp \left( \frac{-1} 2 x^\top V^{-1} x \right) \tag 1 \\[10pt]
& \text{ where } x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\  \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

- Does $\det V$ have a nice closed form?  I suspect it does. (Later note: It does; see below.)
- Does $V^{-1}$ have some nice pattern to it? Again, I suspect so.  So maybe we're not done simplifying $(1)$, but $(1)$ is it.
- You may still have the task of proving that this is the density function ahead of you.  Or maybe you can just cite some theorem in some book you've got.

**PS:** If I'm not mistaken, then when $t_i=i$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ then

- $\det V = 1$. I think I could write a geometric justification for that. And:
- Computation suggests $V^{-1}$ has $2$ in every diagonal entry and $-1$ in every entry immediately adjacent to the diagonal, and $0$ elsewhere.  I suspect I'll realize soon that there's a geometric reason for that.

**PPS:** Elementary row operations find the determinant: $t_1(t_2-t_1)(t_3-t_2) \cdots (t_n-t_{n-1})$.  I think you can also give a geometric argument and a probabilistic argument for that result.

Comment: Indeed there are "probabilistic arguments", see my comment on main.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this idea to find the answer.